# What is the subspace topology on $Y$ if $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the product topology $\mathbb{R}_u \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Say we let $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the x-axis.

I'm trying to figure out *what the subspace topology on $Y$* will be if $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the product topology $\mathbb{R}_u \times \mathbb{R}$

In other words, find the subspace topology of a subset of a space with a particular product topology.

$\mathbb{R}_u$ is the upper limit topology and $\mathbb{R}$ is the standard topology.

We know the product topology on $A \times B$ is the topology with the basis: the collection of all sets $U \times V$ where $U \subset_{op} A$, $V \subset_{op} B$.

The subspace topology is $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{Y \cap U | U \in \mathcal{T}\}$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I feel like the product topology will have a basis of the form $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b] \times (c,d) | a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}, a<b,c<d\}$

We know if $\mathcal{B}$ is the basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\mathcal{B}_Y = \{B \cap Y | B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is the basis for the subspace topology on Y.

So the basis has elements of the form $y \cap ((a,b]\times (c,d))$ for $y \in Y$ and the rest as described above.

My issue is finding the form for the subspace topology using this basis. It is also possible my idea for the product topology basis is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$, then $(a,b]\times(-1,1)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, and intersection with $Y$ is $(a,b]\times\{0\}$. So, $(a,b]$ is an open subset of $Y$. And of $A$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $A=Y\cap A^\star$ for some open subset $A^\star$ of $\Bbb R^2$. If $(y,0)\in A$, then $(y,0)\in A^\star$, and therefore there are numbers $a_y,b_y,c_y,d_y\in\Bbb R$ such that $(y,0)\in(a_y,b_y]\times(c_y,d_y)$ and that $(a_y,b_y]\times(c_y,d_y)\subset A^\star$. But then we have to have $c_y<0<d_y$ and therefore $\bigl((a_y,b_y]\times(c_y,d_y)\bigr)\cap Y=(a_y,b_y]$. And $A=\bigcup_{y\in Y}(a_y,b_y]$. So, $A$ belongs to the upper limit topology.

Therefore, the subspace topology on $Y$ is the upper limit topology.

Comment: Your work is flawless, but I am uncertain why you chose $(-1,1)$ as your initial set. It looks to me that it was chosen simply to show that any arbitrary intersection with $Y$ will produce $\{0\}$ for that pair.

Comment: Yes. I could have chosen $(\alpha,\beta)$, with $\alpha<0<\beta$.